# Execution via node js script with problems

Tags: node.js

Good morning, I have a problem running a command on the linux terminal and returning it to an api, for some reason I get a response on the server that has nothing to do with it, it's as if I just ran the "show route". The answer is in an array but this is normal, the problem is that they have nothing to do with the manual command.

Code:

[image: Code]

Manual command:
[image: Manual command]

Result the server receives:
[image: Result]

Comment: Have you tried exec('/usr/sbin/birdc show route', (err, stdout, stderr)=>{})

Comment: It´s working, thanks! :)

Comment: super! i posted it as solution. lets close up this issue then @tomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
exec('/usr/sbin/birdc show route', (err, stdout, stderr)=>{})
```